# How to give a alert when we select a value from pick list?"

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I have a pick list called System Size(System_Size_SUB_2013__c). When I select an value from pick list I want to give an alert to the user. (Only for a One value, Not all of them). Any idea? Thanks

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.System_Size_SUB_2013__c}" required="true"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the onchange tag? You can embed some javascript in there. Like this:
<apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.System_Size_SUB_2013__c}" required="true" onchange="executeFunctionFoo();"/>

Comment: No I Have not . I will try onchange="executeFunctionFoo(); Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
<apex:page standardController="lead">
    <script>
        function popup(){

            alert("Hello\nHow are you?");           

            }

    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputField value="{!lead.phone}"/>       
        <apex:inputField onchange="popup();" value="{!lead.status}" />
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks, This is working but I only want for one value. In my code it will alert for every value. Any idea how to change it to only one value.

Comment: You are using inputfield ,you are not using any custom controller it means value you are not storing anywhere, whatever value you are selecting , if we use if condition it might only pickup the value which is already stored. you need to store this value through get set properties

Answer (score 1):

If you need for specific value than you would need get the id of that value and whenever selected it shall throw the pop up. Refer to following snippet :  document.getElementById("{!$Component.xyz}:0"); where "xyz" is id of the the entire picklist component and "0" is the index value.

Comment: But I think that value is not stored yet,so this might not work, when a user selects the picklist value it is not save until unless user saves the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<apex:form id="theForm">
    <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="thePageBlockSection">
            <apex:inputField id="myPicklist" value="{!Product_Brief__c.System_Size_SUB_2013__c}" required="true" onchange="myPicklistChanged();"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<script>
    function myPicklistChanged()
    {
        var myPicklistElement = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.thePageBlock.thePageBlockSection.myPicklist}');
        var myPicklistValue = myPicklistElement.options[myPicklistElement.selectedIndex].value;

        if (myPicklistValue == '2000L SUB')
        {
            alert('Your Message');
        }

    }
```

Comment: I believe it does work, though you have lot of missing end tags </apex:pageblock>  :)